# Does "Invisibility" require sight to maintain concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So, one of the spellcasters in my group wants to cast *invisibility* on the thief to have him scout out a dungeon.
The Players Handbook doesn't specifically say the caster must be in sight range of the target and there is a little bit of debate between group members on whether the caster needs to maintain sight range to maintain concentration on the spell, or whether it just works no matter what (checks willing) for an hour.

Comment: Related: [Can you maintain concentration on a spell from another plane?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50160/can-you-maintain-concentration-on-a-spell-from-another-plane?rq=1)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *site range*? Do you mean Line of Sight, the *spell's* range, or both?

Comment: Let's say. No line of sight. The invisible character is in a castle less than 300 yards away. There is no written range for invisibility. The caster is outside the castle  concerning on the invisible character.

Comment: Invisibility would be an *exceedingly* useless spell if concentration required Line of Sight.