# Can you maintain concentration on a spell if you put the target of that spell in a Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, concentration

I’m playing an 6th level Artificer 2 / Bard 4 who took the Bag of Holding at 2nd level.

If I cast *silence* on my Thunder Cannon and place it in the bag of holding, am I able to maintain concentration on the spell?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Can you maintain concentration on a spell from another plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50160/can-you-maintain-concentration-on-a-spell-from-another-plane)

Comment: You should separate your second question into a new question. We only handle one question per post, but you are welcome to make as many question posts as you want! Please take our [tour] when you have a minute to learn more about how we work. And welcome! (I have edited your second question out for you but please do feel free to ask it on another post).

Comment: Alternatively, if you're trying to accomplish a specific trick with this combo of concentrating on a spell and putting it in a bag, please ask about *that* as a complete puzzle for us to answer, instead of asking only about its component parts without telling us what they're for. Asking if it emanates from the bag might be a separate question, or if you're trying to do something tricky, it might be integral to the question — but we would then need to know what trick you're hoping to pull off.

Answer (score 7):

## You do not break concentration just by moving something to a bag of holding

Concentration is broken only under certain conditions:

- You try to cast another concentration spell
- You take damage (and fail your concentration check)
- You become incapacitated or killed.

Beyond that, if an ability does not say it breaks concentration (and there is no ability that I know of that says this), whatever you do you can maintain concentration.

In case this was the source of you confusion, you don't need to maintain line of sight per *[Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-spellcasting)*:

> **If you’re concentrating on a spell, do you need to maintain line of sight with the spell’s target or the spell’s effect?**
>
> You don’t need to be within line of sight or within range to maintain  concentration on a spell, unless a spell’s description or other game feature says otherwise.

Since placing an object in an extraplanar space satisfies none of the conditions for breaking concentration, then you have no issue maintaining your concentration on the spell.

Comment: Thanks, the main reason was so I could drop by gun in the bag if I need to talk / communicate and then pick it back out to return to silent shots